# Playsinline for Video URL Requires 2 Clicks from iOS

Tags: ios, video

Playsinline=1 within my video URL requires 2 clicks from my iOS devices to play it. Is there a way to correct this?

Here is my experience with using playsinline=1 from my iPhone using Google Chrome, Safari & DuckDuckGo:

[embedyt] [https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLI1Ahx4x_H5fqrB6XB4pkeqyo2qsJnDus&layout=gallery&playsinline=1[/embedyt]](https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PLI1Ahx4x_H5fqrB6XB4pkeqyo2qsJnDus&layout=gallery&playsinline=1%5B/embedyt%5D)

Here is where it starts. I click on the Play Button. Note: As you can see, the Play Button is not red.

‘https://savvyify.com/img/image/CQFB’

After clicking the Play Button, it acts like it wants to play, but then returns to the Play Button, which is red – see next image.

‘https://savvyify.com/img/image/CUJu’

After the two steps above occur, then I have a red Play Button and the video plays inline.

‘https://savvyify.com/img/image/CWrj’

Is there a way to correct this to where the video will play inline on the first click?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer within the Plug-in I'm using; EmbedPlus Plug-in for YouTube. It had an `iOSPlayback` feature that automatically includes `Playsinline=1` and the videos play from an iOS device on 1st click